# Somewhat vague syntax for creating an object in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private fun changeState() {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        myName.name = "Henok"
        binding.invalidateAll();
    }, 2000);
}
```

postDelayed(runnable, time), it accepts both runnable and time, but here we pass a literal object to the runnable argument. So can you please explain how the runnable object is created, kotlin syntax?

Comment: Side note: both semicolons aren't necessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, kotlin internally handles the creation of those objects for you and instead just requires you to define what to do with the logic of the created `run` method internally. Kotlin doesn't always require you to override an object/interface to achieve callbacks

```
fun example(callback:() -> Unit){

}
```

you would then call and use this function as:

```
example {
//do some stuff here, as this is the callback method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing "a literal object", that's how [lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) are written in Kotlin. And you can use a lambda here because `Runnable` is a [Java interface with a single abstract method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).